# What if we test three photons instead of two in Bell's paradox?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, probability, bells-inequality

I am not a physicist and do not know anything about quantum mechanics (except that it can be formulated using Hilbert spaces), but watching a vulgarization video about Bell's paradox, I had a question that I do not know how to answer. Please excuse me if what I say is nonsensical.

In the video, Bell's paradox is formulated as follows. We have an entangled pair of photons with superposed state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left|H\right>⊗\left|H\right>+\left|V\right>⊗\left|V\right>)$ where $H$ is horizontal polarization and $V$ vertical polarization. I do not really know what polarization means, so maybe it makes no sense at all. To me it is only an element of some finite dimensional Hilbert space. We have three filters $A$, $B$ and $C$ with respective angles 0°, 22.5° and 45°. For each pair of filters, we can test the two photons with these filters and we get some probability distribution on the four possible outcomes.

As I understand the paradox, there is no probability distribution on the space of eight possible outcomes for each of the three filters ($2^3 = 8$) such that it is coherent with the probabilities given by testing only with two filters. Nonetheless, if we take three entangled photons instead of two, and test these photons with filters $A$, $B$ and $C$, we should get a probability distribution on the space of eight possible outcomes. So I was wondering what is this probability distribution, if we suppose the state of the three entangled photons is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left|HHH\right> + \left|VVV\right>)$.

How can we compute this probability distribution (if we can stay at the level of finite dimensional Hilbert spaces) and what is it? How does this probability distribution relate to the three probability distributions associated to each pair of filters?

I invented some calculations that worked with two photons (it gives the right probabilities) but I suspect they make no sense at all, so I'm not including them to shorten my post. If I try to apply it to three photons, it gives things that cannot be true because they are not rotation-invariant.

Moreover, I cannot imagine that if we run the experience with three photons, the probabilities can be different depending on if we keep the result from the last photon or not. What would be the "boundary" between the experience with two photons and the experience with one more photon? (Imagine the experimenters did not realize one more photon was emitted and tested by error, or something like that.)

I hope there is not too many conceptual misunderstandings in what I wrote. If so, what are they?

Comment: The joint probability distribution you're seeking  depends on the initial state of your three-photon system.

Comment: @WillO I had in mind the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left|HHH\right> + \left|VVV\right>)$. I did not notice that the state of the triplet was not fully determined by the three "restrictions" to each state of pairs of photons. But these projection matrices to restrict the states are not unitary of course... For instance the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}(\left|HHH\right>-\left|HHV\right>-\left|HVH\right>+\left|HVV\right>-\left|VHH\right>+\left|VHV\right>+\left|VVH\right>-\left|VVV\right>)$ (we put a + coefficient if the number of $V$s is even) would be sent (cont.)

Comment: ...to the state $0$ by each restriction forgetting one of the photons. Probably I cannot avoid proper learning since the images I have in mind make no sense at all... Maybe it doesn't make sense in the quantum formalism to "forget a photon"? Anyway I would just like to see the computation for this state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left|HHH\right> + \left|VVV\right>)$ if it is not too much work for someone and not considered as "homework" or something along these lines. (Or if someone has a good reference maybe 30 pages where I can learn how to do that.)

Comment: I meant that I cannot invest right now in reading a whole book so if there is a short reference staying at the level of finite dimensional Hilbert spaces, I would love it. But I believe my question doesn't belong to this website as I can read [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8944/very-naive-questions)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the recipe for doing your calculation.

First, I assume you mean an initial state of $\sigma=(1/\sqrt2)(HHH+VVV)$.

The possible outcomes for going through the zero-degree filter are $H$ and $V$.

The possible outcomes for going through the $\pi/8$ filter are $X=\cos(\pi/8)H+\sin(\pi/8)V$ and $Y=\cos(5\pi/8)H+\sin(5\pi/8)V$.

The possible outcomes for going through the $\pi/4$ filter are $Z=(\cos(\pi/4)H+\sin(\pi/4)V$ and $W=\cos(\pi/4)H+\sin(3\pi/4)V$.

Therefore the eight possible outcomes for your experiment are $HXZ,HXW,HYZ,HYW,VXZ,VXW,VYZ,VYW$.  Call these $T_1,\ldots T_8$.

To interpret these, use the distributive law so  that $HXZ=H\Big(\cos(\pi/8)H+\sin(\pi/8)V\Big)\Big(\cos(\pi/4)H+\sin(\pi/4)V\Big)$ is a sum of four nonzero terms, of which the first is $(\cos(\pi/8))(\cos(\pi/4))HHH$.

Now take your initial state $(1/\sqrt3)(HHH+VVV)$ and write it (uniquely) in the form $\alpha_1 T_1+\ldots \alpha_8T_8$.

Then the probability that you'll observe the outcome $T_i$ is $|\alpha_i|^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think I mean $1/\sqrt{2}$ and not $1/\sqrt{3}$, otherwise the norm would be $2/3$ instead of $2/2=1$, right?

Actually, what you say here is exactly the naive computation I did and whose results I did not trust... I expressed it as follows instead. Define a "rotation" $r$ such that $r(H)=\cos(\theta)H+\sin(\theta)V$ and $r(V)=-\sin(\theta)H+\cos(\theta)V$. Let $r'$ be an other rotation. Then $\mathrm{id}⊗r⊗r'$ sends our state to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(Hr(H)r'(H) + Vr(V)r'(V))$.

Comment: If we write $A$, $B$ and $C$ for the three filters corresponding to the three rotations, this induces the right probabilities for the pair $AB$ and $AC$, but not for the pair $BC$! (since this would be impossible to have such a distribution anyway) Because of such an asymmetry, I thought it was nonsense.

But I believe my assumption that the result should be rotation-invariant is incorrect. Rotation-invariant means that if we rotate each filter by some angle, we do not see the difference. It is the case if we only have two photons but it seems to be just a coincidence!

Comment: So now I do not understand how the results of a statistical test can differ depending on this last photon, but this is probably an other question.

Comment: You're right about the $\sqrt2$.  I am editing to correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use three-photon states, you can do even better than Bell's inequality, you can prepare a Greenberger–Horne–Zeilinger (GHZ) state which allows you to make an entirely *deterministic* test of hidden variable and quantum mechanical theories, unlike the Bell inequality which relies on relative probabilities. In other words, you get an absolutely true or false experiment about the validity of quantum theory by using the GHZ state, if you do it correctly.

This GHZ state is written as
$$\vert GHZ \rangle = \frac{\vert 000\rangle +\vert 111\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$$

You can read about the GHZ experiment at its wiki page here:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GHZ_experiment

Comment: Wha, thank you for the keyword, I will look that up and see what I understand!

Comment: Ok, so moreover what is said on Wikipedia confirms the computations provided by WillO: "For instance, if the polarization of two of the photons are measured and determined to be rotated +45° from horizontal, then local hidden variable theory predicts that the polarization of the third photon will also be +45° from horizontal. However, quantum mechanical theory predicts that it will be +45° from vertical."