# If the spins of three electrons which were once close (but are now far away from each other) are measured, what will be the outcome?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, measurements

I know that if you measure the spins of two electrons that were once close enough to interact (but now separated light-years in space) the outcomes of the measurements will opposite to each other (entanglement). But what if a third electron (far away from both and once interacting with both mentioned) is involved? What will be the outcomes if you measure the spin of all three?
If the first one is measured to have spin up, then we know that if the spin of the second is measured it must have spin down. But what if the third spin is measured? To which measured spin of the others it has to conform? Or can it just be up as well as down?

Comment: Related question: [What if we test three photons instead of two in Bell's paradox?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/592901/179151)

Comment: @BioPhysicist So we can, in principle, also measure that two electrons have equal spin?

Comment: *I know that if you measure the spins of two electrons that were once close enough to interact (but now separated light-years in space) the outcomes of the measurements will opposite to each other*  Does "I know" mean "I just made this up" or does it mean "I have an argument in mind that implies this"?  If the latter, please edit to include your argument and I will be happy to help you find the error.

Comment: @WillO I assumed it to be common knowledge. But I already know by now that you can also measure the two spins to be up.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that if you measure the spins of two electrons that were once close enough to interact … the outcomes of the measurements will opposite to each other.

Not necessarily, if a pair of electrons is in the spin state $\lvert\upuparrows\rangle$ (such as in [orthohelium](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/helium.html)), then you will measure the spins to be the same. Likewise, with three electrons, you can either find that all the spins are the same or that one is different, depending on what state they are in.

The only reason that a pair of electrons would need to have opposite spins is if they were in the same "orbital" state (same state except for spin). Since there are only two linearly independent spin states for spin-$\frac12$, there can be no more than two electrons in the same orbital state. As such, there is not an analogous situation for three electrons.

Comment: This I can understand. But what for far away electrons?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder As long as moving the electrons apart doesn't change their spin states, you get the same results.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that if we measure the spins of two faraway electrons we could get the result that we measure both to have spin up?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder yes, for example if you separated the two electrons of an orthohelium atom, you would measure them to have the same spin.

Comment: Ah! I always thought that when you measure the spins of two faraway spins they have to be opposite. Obviously not!